# Python - Store function with parameters

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for a simple trivia game. There are several buttons, one for each answer, and I'd like to run a checkAnswer function with certain parameters when one is clicked.

If I used something like the following:

```
self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", command=self.checkAnswer(question=3, answer=2))
```

Then it would run checkAnswer and use what it returned (nothing).

Is there a simple way to store the parameters in the button constructor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is exactly what [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is designed to do:

```
>>> import functools
>>> print_with_hello = functools.partial(print, "Hello")
>>> print_with_hello("World")
Hello World
>>> print_with_hello()
Hello
```

`partial()` returns a new function that behaves just as the old one, but with any arguments you passed in filled, so in your case:

```
import functools

...

self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", command=functools.partial(self.checkAnswer, question=3, answer=2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a higher order function to wrap your `checkAnswer` function. This would allow you to return a function that wouldn't require any parameters, and therefore could be used as a callback.

For example:

```
def makeCheckAnswer(self, **kwargs)
    return lambda: self.checkAnswer(**kwargs)
```

This would make your button initialization:

```
self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", command=self.makeCheckAnswer(question=3, answer=2))
```

Comment: I won't -1, but this is reinventing the wheel. `functools.partial()` does this.

Comment: That's neat, and a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By far easiest is just to use lambda in place

```
self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", 
    command=lambda: self.checkAnswer(question=3, answer=2))
```

Though, in a similar but a bit more complicated cases, you really should use a function factory such as

```
def answerCheckerFactory(self, question, answer):
    def checker():
        return self.checkAnswer(question, answer)

    return checker

    ...
    self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", 
        command=self.answerCheckerFactory(question=3, answer=2))
```

because it would make sure that you pass in correct arguments (not `quetsion` (sic) for example); notice the difference from `functools.partial` which allows you to mistype the function arguments and get an exception only when clicked on the button ;)

Also, hardcoding the questions / answers in the button code does not seem right...

Comment: I completely disagree, this is less clear, and reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I wouldn't hardcode it, that was just an example. I don't mind if I get a delayed exception either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have functions that have specific parameters (that dont rely on things like `text.get()`) you can use wrappers for it, which would be the easiest way to do this, other than lambada functions. For example:

```
def option1wrapper():
    ClassName.checkAnswer(question=3,answer=2)
self.option1 = Button(frame, text="1842", command=option1wrapper)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to use a lambda function like this

```
self.option1 = lambda: Button(frame, text="1842", command=self.checkAnswer(question=3, answer=2))
```